# Cuales son los pasos para solucionar conflctos en GIT?

Tags: git

tengo el siguiente problema con git, este problema fue generado por `git rebase dev`, anteriormente tengo mi branch arriba(esta remoto y listo para ser mergeado a la rama develop pero esta 4 commits behind) quiero actualizar mi rama.

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: Issue 135 homepage refresh
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
<stdin>:17: trailing whitespace.
      %h4 
warning: 1 line adds whitespace errors.
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging app/views/layouts/application.html.haml
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app/views/layouts/application.html.haml
Auto-merging app/views/home/index.html.haml
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app/views/home/index.html.haml
Auto-merging app/views/home/_group_projects.html.haml
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app/views/home/_group_projects.html.haml
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 Issue 135 homepage refresh

When you have resolved this problem run "git rebase --continue".
If you would prefer to skip this patch, instead run "git rebase --skip".
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing run "git rebase --abort".
```

que puedo hacer para solucionarlo?

lo que quiero hacer es:

1. solucionar los conflictos
2. git add a todos los archivos solucionados (es necesario?)
3. git rebase --continue
4. git commit -m "nuevo commit"
5. git push -f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando se ha generado un conflicto, en el archivo en el que se ha generado aparece la siguiente estructura:

```
<<<<<<<<HEAD
Contenido en la rama donde hacemos el merge

============

Cambios en la rama que queremos unir

>>>>>>>>>>>
```

Lo que debes hacer es entrar en el archivo y modificar esta parte con el contenido tal cual quieres que quede al finalizar la unión de ramas. Si quieres quedarte con una de las dos opciones, algunos editores de texto como ATOM te dan la opción de elegir directamente clicando sobre la parte del HEAD o la otra, haciendo bastante ágil la opción de elegir como dejar el documento.

Una vez hecho esto debes realizar el git add y git commit y podrás fusionar tu rama.

Te dejo dos link donde lo explican algo más detallado:
[Línea de comandos](https://help.github.com/es/enterprise/2.19/user/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line)
[Conflictos después de rebase](https://help.github.com/es/github/using-git/resolving-merge-conflicts-after-a-git-rebase)

Comment: hola, quiero actulizar mi rama remota, entonces le debo dar push?

Comment: Sí, después del git commit deberás realizar el push.

Comment: pero porque debo dar push si mi rama local estaba limpia, solo son los conflictos que debo subir para actualizar mi rama remota?

Comment: El conflicto se genera porque existe una diferencia entre el archivo que tienes en tu rama local y el archivo que tienes en tu rama remota. Por tanto, cuando corriges esos errores que te dan el conflicto, esa correción la tienes en tu rama local. Para hacerla visible en tu rama remota debes realizar el push como cuando realizas un commit normal.

Comment: una cosa mas si solamente quiero actualizar mi rama remota porque estaba 4 commits behind suponiendo que no tengo conflictos, como la actualizo?

Comment: Lo siento, no he entendido qué es a lo que te refieres.

Comment: lo que pasa es que mi rama remota esta atrasada con 4 commits behind del branch develop remoto, para ser mergeado tiene que estar actualizado mi rama